# Trotter product formula with complex exponent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

If $A$ and $B$ are bounded operators, one version of Trotter product formula is:
$$e^{A+B} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg{(}e^{i\frac{A}{n}}e^{i\frac{B}{n}}\bigg{)}^{n}$$
where the limit is with respect to the norm topology. This result is not difficult to prove. But I'd like to prove the analogous version when the exponents carry an $i$ factor. The result is as follows.

**Theorem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be self-adjoint operators such that $A+B$ is essentially self-adjoint on its common domain. Then:
$$e^{i(A+B)}=s-\lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg{(}e^{i\frac{A}{n}}e^{i\frac{B}{n}}\bigg{)}^{n} $$
holds. Here, $s-lim_{n\to \infty}$ means the limit is taken with respect to the strong operator topology.

**Question:** How can I prove the above theorem?

Comment: Try to write $e^{i(A+B)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg{(}e^{i\frac{A}{n}}e^{i\frac{B}{n}}\bigg{)}^{n}$, consistently!